# React routing not working v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to route multiple pages using `BrowserRouter`. Many of the guides online are outdated and do not work with Reactv4. Here's what I'm doing:

Index.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import SignIn from './components/SignIn';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';
import ForgotPass from './components/ForgotPass';

ReactDOM.render((<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={SignIn}/>
    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
    <Route path="/forgot" component={ForgotPass}/>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('root'));
```

And then I create hyperlinks to those pages using:

```js
<a href="/forgot">Forgot password?</a>
```

But when I click the hyperlink it just loads the same page again.

Also: I've seen some guides use the App component, I wasn't sure if that is something predefined in React and if it was needed, as I need the SignIn component to be the default page.

Comment: Switch will only route to the first thing it matches, and the first thing that '/forgot' matches is '/'. Did you perhaps mean to pass `exact` into the route for '/' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the exact flat on your root path. Otherwise it will match in the switch before it gets to the lower routes.

```
 <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn}/>
    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
    <Route path="/forgot" component={ForgotPass}/>
 </Switch>
```

OR move it to the end:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
    <Route path="/forgot" component={ForgotPass}/>
    <Route path="/" component={SignIn}/>
 </Switch>
```

Comment: For some reason my Atom IDE changes (exact) to (exact="exact") whenever I saved it so I removed it. But moving it to the end works perfectly!

Comment: Not sure why your ide would do that (perhaps a lint rule), but try `exact={true}`, which is what `exact` on its own is a shorthand for